# UWP x:Bind twoway requires Converter?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, xbind

I am using a Content control that is bound to my ViewModel.SeletedLogItem property, which is of type LogItemDTO, which is specified in the DataTemplate's DataType.  When I set the binding to `Mode=TwoWay` I get a compile error saying I need a converter.

> Invalid binding path 'ViewModel.SelectedLogItem' : Cannot bind type 'LifeLog.Data.DomainEntities.LogItemDTO' to 'System.Object' without a converter

Below is part of my viewmodel and the xaml for the content control

```cs
public class LogItemEditPageViewModel : LifeLog.App.Mvvm.ViewModelBase
{
    #region Properties

    private LogItemInfo OriginalData { get; set;}

    private LogItemDTO selectedLogItem;
    public LogItemDTO SelectedLogItem { get { return selectedLogItem; } set { Set(ref selectedLogItem, value); } }
```

```xml
<ContentControl Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedLogItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
<ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate  x:DataType="dat:LogItemDTO">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Log, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="15" Height="450" Width="728"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        AcceptsReturn="True"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource Yell}" Background="{StaticResource DGreen}"
                        />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10, 10,10" >
                    <TextBlock Text="LastUpdated:" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LastUpdated}" Foreground="{StaticResource DGreen}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10" >
                    <TextBlock Text="Date Added:" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DateAdded}" Foreground="{StaticResource DGreen}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Romasz how did you edit my post to get color?  I surrounded my code with the {} tag.  What else should I do?

Comment: You can always click edit and see the changes. To make it color, I've put `<!-- language: c# -->` before code part and `<!-- language: xaml -->` before xaml part. Normally if you put only one code, SO should recognize the language, but in your case two parts were close each other and language hasn't been recognized.

Comment: Hi, the framework needs to know how to write data to the bound instance of LogItemDTO. A converter will help it to solve this problem.
Check this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101.aspx

Comment: Danvy, thanks for the note.  I will view jerry's post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do binding with a converter, but you will need to write the converter

something like:

```cs
public class XConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter)
            {//return converted value
                return (
             //do something here                
               }
        }
```

Then binding

```xml
<TextBox  Converter={StaticResource XConverter}></TextBox>
```